# .htaccess | Add a trailing slash to URL only if the path is a folder / directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to create a rule where a trailing slash is added automatically if the URL path points to a folder / directory and not a file. For example the images folder:

```
http://example.com/images
```

to become

```
http://example.com/images/
```

Somehow some browsers do this automatically but I need my server to handle it first through my rules. On the other hand I have rules that redirect certain URLS to a file for example:

```
http://example.com/home
```

gets opened by

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=home
```

So in this case I don't want to add the trailing slash since home points to a file and `http://example.com/home/` with a trailing slash will just redirect to a not found page.

Here is what I have so far but I get a 500 error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

To my understanding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` checks and applies all the following rules if the URL is a folder/directory.
Then with `RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [QSA]` I am trying to add a slash at the end and also allow any query string to sent, I believe here is where I have my error, finally I understand that `RewriteRule .* - [L]` stops checking if the URL is a directory and lets the rest of the rules work normal.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: A first glimpse tells me your regex should be: `/([^/]+)$ $1/`

Comment: It is written in my question: "I understand that RewriteRule .* - [L] stops checking if the URL is a directory and lets the rest of the rules work normal."

Comment: You are missing the point of the question, I know I am wrong and thats why I posted this question, I also wrote "I understand". meaning "I am not sure". Back to your statement, I do have RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d but maybe you can explain me why I am wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, did you try Starkeen's answer below?

Comment: Still testing. Not working 100% Thanks,

Comment: What part is not working?

Comment: It is better but now my css files return not found errors and obviously the site looks like crap

Comment: Just fyi there is no need of a rule for adding trailing slash to directories as that will already happen with `mod_dir` module

Comment: And your CSS problem can be fixed by adding `<base href="/" />` to the head section of your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an infinite loop error from the code

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [QSA]
```

Because the pattern also matches the target, and on the second iteration **/dir/** rewrites to **/dir/** causing the loop error.

You need a RewriteCond to prevent this

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ says "Dont redirect /foo/ to /foo/

Comment: Can you explain what RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ does, Thanks!

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ says "Dont redirect **/foo/** to **/foo/** ".

Comment: Why [L,R] instead of [QSA], I still want to be able to send query strings and allow other rules to check. BTW It didn't work, now my css files are returning not found :(

Comment: @multimediaxp QSA flag is not required in your Rule, because query strings are automatically appended from old url to new. QSA is helpful when Your target url  and old url both contain query strings ,then qsa appends the old query strings to new query strings.

Comment: CSS js and other relative urls can be solved by adding **<base href="/">** to the head section of your webpage.